# Filter current dates only in ng-repeat array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a filter which needs to return only current dates in a data array:

```
app.filter('currentDates', function() {
  return function(eventdata) {
    var data_date, filtered_list, i, today;
    filtered_list = [];
    i = 0;
    while (i < eventdata.length) {
      today = Date.now();
      data_date = eventdata.date;
      if (today <= data_date) {
        filtered_list.push(data[i]);
      }
      i++;
    }
    return filtered_list;
  };
});
```

I'm calling the filter in the html like so:

```
<div class="event" ng-repeat="data in eventdata | currentDates"></div>
```

I can't figure out why nothing is being returned. Any help appreciated. Here's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/5aT4CF?p=preview. If you remove the filter the data populates.

Comment: you date is in string format and you are comparing string with date type and event data is array not single object

Comment: So what would the corrected filter look like IYO?

Comment: I have posted my answer @Ezra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your eventdata is array not single object
2. You are comparing string with date
3. You are pushing data[i] instead of eventdata[i]

Try like this

```
while (i < eventdata.length) { 
  today = Date.now();
  data_date = new Date(eventdata[i].date);
  if (today <= data_date) {
    filtered_list.push(eventdata[i]);
  }
  i++;
}
```

<kbd>**[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/nE2GTF5EroeRrSAc1Mdp?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I see now. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As was explained in the comments, you are comparing a Date type with a string. You need to perform type conversion on that string.

I also went with a `for loop` instead of a `while loop` to save a couple of lines of space.

Your filter function should look like this

```
app.filter('currentDates', function() {
    return function(eventdata) {
        var filtered_list = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < eventdata.length; i++) {
            var today = Date.now();
            var data_date = new Date(eventdata[i].date).getTime();
            if (today <= data_date) {
                filtered_list.push(eventdata[i]);
            }
        }
    return filtered_list;
    };
});
```

Here is the updated plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/qZrQEOJDtyBOWSkNnrZS?p=preview